# Can't switch back from noveau driver to nvidia proprietry driver

Tags: nvidia

today out of curiousity i switched back to noveau driver from my nvidia proprietry 310 driver all went well but now when i tried to enable the proprietry driver my system automatically reverted back to noveau and i am getting big ugly screen of 640 x 800 resolution please help and fortunately i had created a back of my whole filesystem (/) and stored it in my windows partion so if i reinstall ubuntu then how can i restore from backup my applications and settings .please help

Comment: `grep -iRnH "blacklist nouveau" /etc/modprobe.d/*.conf` shows any output? Also what happens when you reinstall nVidia driver by `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates`?  After reboot do you get a proper screen resolution then?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Samik for your reply but I found a solution for this problem and it worked, at least for me.

What I did was copy all the nVidia drives files (`.deb` files) from my `/var/cache/apt/archive` and pasted them on the Desktop, then opened a terminal and typed the following:

```
cd Desktop
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Then waited for the installation to complete, then I typed `sudo nvidia-xconfig`, then restarted my system.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I'm sorry but I just want to make sure, are you Arnav803 and answering your own question?

Comment: Yeah, Alaa you are right it is me (Arnav803) who answered my own  question :) actually I asked it without logging in or registering my self.

Comment: You should try logging into the other account in order to [accept an answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) =). Also, you should [contact AskUbuntu to merge your accounts](http://askubuntu.com/help/merging-accounts).